# Los JPanel no cambian con un JButton

Tags: java, jpanel

Estoy intentando hacer un punto de venta para un proyecto escolar pero no puedo cambiar los paneles con botones, NetBeans me detecta que hago algo cuando presiono otro boton que tengo incluido para otras cosas pero al presionar los incluidos en el codigo de ejemplo no tira nada, no pude encontrar una diferencia entre ellos. Abajo el codigo de las cosas en cuestion (probablemente falte algo que exclui para mostrar solo lo relevante?)

````
public class Venta extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel sell,book;
    JLabel InPlu,tituloC;
    public Venta() {
        setTitle("Punto de Venta");
        setSize(900, 900);
        setLocation(10,20);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        sell=new JPanel();
        sell.setBounds(10,20,800,800);
        add(sell);
        sell.setVisible(true);
        book=new JPanel();
        book.setBounds(10,20,800,800);
        add(book);
        book.setVisible(false);
        inicializar();
    }
    public final void inicializar(){
        InPlu=new JLabel("Codigo:");
        InPlu.setLocation(20,60);
        InPlu.setSize(100,30);
        sell.add(InPlu);

        tituloC=new JLabel("Consultas");
        tituloC.setBounds(20,30,100,30);
        book.add(tituloC);

        btnCon = new JButton("Consultar");
        btnCon.setBounds(80,300,100,30);
        btnCon.addActionListener(this);
        sell.add(btnCon);
        
        btnElim = new JButton("Eliminar Articulos");
        btnElim.setBounds(80,350,100,30);
        btnElim.addActionListener(this);
        sell.add(btnElim);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object control=e.getSource();
        if(control.equals(btnVenta)){
            int PLU = Integer.parseInt(cajaReg.getText());
            anadir=mt.carro(PLU);
        }
        if(control.equals(btnCon)){
            sell.setVisible(false);
            book.setVisible(true);
        }
        if(control.equals(btnElim)){
            sell.setVisible(true);
            book.setVisible(false);
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

No está muy claro lo que pretendes hacer ni cual es el fallo que te da. He ejecutado tu código y la acción asociada a los botones que aparecen ahí se ejecuta correctamente:

- Cuando pulsas el botón "Consultar", el panel sell se hace invisible y el panel book se hace visible. Al estar los dos botones asociados al panel sell, ambos desaparecen y no se puede volver a la situación original.
- Cuando pulsas el botón "Eliminar articulos", el panel sell se hace visible y el panel book se hace invisible. Como esta es la situación de partida, no hay cambios apreciables.

Quizás lo que estás intentando implementar es un TabbedPane, un panel con pestañas, de forma que cada pestaña contenga unos elementos específicos y permita ejecutar una funcionalidad específica.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo ejecutable de un TabbedPane, he cogido el que aparece en el [manual online de Oracle sobre Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) y lo he adaptado ligeramente a lo que aparece en tu pregunta.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {
    public TabbedPaneDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Consultas", null, panel1,"Does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Eliminar articulos", null, panel2,"Does twice as much nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

        JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Otros 3", null, panel3,"Still does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

        JComponent panel4 = makeTextPanel("Panel #4");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Otros 4", null, panel4,"Does nothing at all");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);

        //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
        add(tabbedPane);

        //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.
     * For thread safety, this method should be invoked from the event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Punto de venta");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new TabbedPaneDemo(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setLocation(10,20);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

En este código, podemos destacar el componente `JTabbedPane`, al cual se añaden 4 `JPanel`, cada uno de los cuales representa un tab o pestaña. Al pulsar en cada pestaña, el correspondiente panel se hace visible y el resto se ocultan automáticamente, sin que tengas que implementar explícitamente este mecanismo. Dentro de cada uno de estos JPanel puedes añadir los elementos que quieras.

A partir del enlace que he puesto arriba, puedes acceder a distintos ejemplos que usan tabs o pestañas, por si alguno se adecua más a lo que quieres hacer.